# how to find unique values with matlab in cell array

Tags: matlab, find, unique, unique-values

How do I find unique cells in excel using matlab? i was trying to get all unique strings in some excel field,
so baisicly im trying to do somthing like this:

```
[~,~,mainraw] = xlsread(mainfilename,1); 
unique_expense_types = unique(mainraw(:,2));
```

it should have goten all the cells into cell array type and then return full strings that are unique, though i receive this output:

```
ans =

'  "'()-./01245689BEGILMORWY'
```

please help fixing it

Comment: It looks like the input to `unique` is a char array, not a cell array of char arrays. Please include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code that can be un as is

Comment: Try `unique(cellstr(mainraw(:,2)));`, but without us knowing what's in your Excel it's hard to say

Comment: This statement "it should have goten all the cells into cell array type and then return full strings that are unique" is not true **unless** the input is a cell array of character array, which is not always the case when you use the `raw` output from `xlsread`. And, of course, you are able to see how the inclusion of a (minimal) example would've characterized your question differently (and probably better).